# Javascript Funciton Inner/Outer/Variable Scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I've read the MDN:Scope document and other resources but feel genuinely stuck.

```
var funkyFunction = function() {
  return function() {
    return "FUNKY!"
  }
}

// We want to set theFunk equal to "FUNKY!" using our funkyFunction.
// NOTE: you only need to modify the code below this line.

var theFunk = funkyFunction()
theFunk()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: There is no question in this post.

Comment: I needed clarification on invoking that internal function using the //marked-out// directions. I should have included more detail in my post though you are right. Thank you both for your responses. I will also refer to that link now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`funkyFunction` returns a function. You need to call that function immediately, so that it returns `"FUNKY!"` and gets assigned to `theFunk`:

```js
var funkyFunction = function() {
  return function() {
    return "FUNKY!"
  }
}

// We want to set theFunk equal to "FUNKY!" using our funkyFunction.
// NOTE: you only need to modify the code below this line.

var theFunk = funkyFunction()();
console.log(theFunk);
```

Comment: Ah this was the answer and makes so much sense.  Thank you very much CertainPerformance.